# Explaining the color of objects: classification and molecular perspective

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

### Intro

I have been interested in this topic for a while, at the conceptual level.

Normally we group interaction of objects with light as as reflection, transmission and absorption/emission.

I'd like to narrow those down a bit and ask a few questions at the end of the summary.

Besides, it seems that Scattering is diffuse reflection. Which is one of the questions at the bottom.

For both Scattering and Reflection it seems enough to imagine some type of surface and the light as beams of light.

### Summary of Ideas

1. **Scattering:** This "echoes" the light in different directions with different intensity.
   There are at least 2 different types of scattering:

- Rayleight (psize << lambda): It is that it scatters more for shorter wavelengths (example blue of sky)
- Mie (psize ~ lambda)

2. **Reflection**

- Specular reflection_ Occurs when the material "echoes" the incident light, with same angle (relative to the surface normal line).
- *[Diffuse reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection)* seems quite similar to Scattering. Yet the article says:

> Few materials do not cause diffuse reflection: among these are metals, which do not allow light to enter; gases, liquids, glass,
> The incident light ray is somewhat reflected to every direction (i.e broadcasted), and it is more intense in the direction normal to the surface (Lambert cosine law). It seems that as a difference to Scattering, we only focus on the reflected light.

Diffuse reflection is actually the main reason why we see objects, if there were much specular reflection we would see the reflection and would be a lot more like a mirror. Then, the color itself will depend on absorption.

3. **Absortion** and **Emission**, in this case it is necessary to talk about the electronic structure. It also includes a huge n
   umber of phenomenons. The best simplified description I know of is the [Jablonski diagram](https://%20%20Is%20this%20type%20of%20scattering%20lambertian%20in%20type?).
4. **Transmission:** not very relevant either but included for completion (see first paragraphs).

   - **Refraction** just included for completeness but this normally isn't responsible for the color of objects.

### Question

I thought that would be useful to know which type of explanation I'd expect. And also expose it for corrections and maybe important missing phenomenons.

- Is Scattering Lambertian in type? Is it phenomenologically the same than *diffuse reflection*? If not, why.
- When light is not electronically absorbed by atoms and molecules, but instead it is reflected or scattered, what would be the molecular/atomic phenomenon that explains it (reflection) ?